# Do I need to use this.notifyPath when using Polymer array mutation methods?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I was under the impression that something like:

```
this.push('zone.items', item);
```

would be enough to have a parent polymer component observing `zone.item` notified of the change. However, I need to add

```
this.notifyPath('zone.items');
```

for it to work. To me this doesn't seem to comply with the information [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#work-with-arrays).

Comment: The problem could be the fact that you are updating a `subproperty` of an object. [More info here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#notify-path).

Comment: @LasaleFamine Yes, I guess that is what's happening - I assumed that binding to a subproperty directly will be notified when the subproperty changes, it seems that is not the case.

Comment: Anyway, if I can, I always prefer "re-set" the property to update the DOM like: `this.set('zone.items', aBrandNewArray)`.

Comment: @LasaleFamine That's what I ended up doing but I'm worried I'm adding too many quite data intensive operations through that "hack"...

Comment: I think that if you do this just when you need to update the DOM (or call an observer), this is quite legit (or maybe the only solution without the `notifyPath`)! Of course we don't want to work with mutable methods like `push` in these days :D